# How to access the boolean value of child's property "checked" in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dom

I want to access the boolean value of child's property "checked" in ReactJS. Now I have the following render method.

***Class LoginCard.js***

```
render() {
    return (
        <Card style={styles.card}>
            <UserIcon/>
            <UPSection ref="inputs" updateUName={this.updateInputState_Username} updatePWord={this.updateInputState_Password}/>
            <RememberMe ref="RemMeChk"/> //This conponent containing the checkbox.
            <LoginBtn onClick={this.handleLoginBtnClicked}/>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

I want to get the bool `checked` value in component `RememberMe`. The following shows you the render method of `RememberMe`.

***Class RememberMe.js***

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={styles.div}>
            <Checkbox ref="rm" label="Remember Me" labelStyle={styles.text} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The component `Checkbox` is from [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox) and it has the property of `checked`. I try to use `var isRemMeChked = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.RemMeChk.refs.rm).checked;` inside the class LoginCard to access the bool value but it is undefined. What is the proper way to access the bool value?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the value in RememberMe.js

**RememberMe.js**

```
getValue() {
   return this.refs.rm.checked;
}
render() {

    return (
        <div style={styles.div}>
            <Checkbox ref="rm" label="Remember Me" labelStyle={styles.text} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Login Card**
        getValue() {
             return this.refs.RemMeChk.getValue()
        }
    render() {

```
    return (
        <Card style={styles.card}>
            <UserIcon/>
            <UPSection ref="inputs" updateUName={this.updateInputState_Username} updatePWord={this.updateInputState_Password}/>
            <RememberMe ref="RemMeChk"/> //This conponent containing the checkbox.
            <LoginBtn onClick={this.handleLoginBtnClicked}/>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why you can declare a method inside render method?

Comment: I tested that the method return properly but `this.refs.rm.checked` is `undefined`. I also tested to return `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.rm).checked` but it is also `undefined`. How to get the checked bool value in Checkbox? The documentation stated that there is a property `checked`.